# Ionic 3 Build app failed due to addition of Firebase Cloud Messaging plugin

Tags: android, firebase, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging, cordova-plugin-fcm

I have installed Firebase Cloud Messaging plugin for my Ionic 3 application with push notifications. But, suddenly it cause me a build error after it was installed.  Here's what I got:

**Error script:**

```
 * Where:
Script 'C:\Users\Kyle Louise Villar\QuickEApp\platforms\android\cordova-plugin- 
fcm\quicke-FCMPlugin.gradle' line: 13

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating script.
> Failed to apply plugin [class 
'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
   > For input string: "+"
```

I just checked my **project.properties** file, but seemed nothing happened when I changed the versions of the following properties.

**project.properties**

```
target=android-27
android.library.reference.1=CordovaLib
android.library.reference.2=app
cordova.system.library.1=com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.10.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.android.support:customtabs:23.3.0
cordova.system.library.3=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.gradle.include.1=cordova-plugin-browsertab/quicke-BrowserTab.gradle
cordova.gradle.include.2=cordova-plugin-buildinfo/quicke-BuildInfo.gradle
cordova.system.library.4=com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.37.0
cordova.system.library.5=com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.8.0
cordova.gradle.include.3=cordova-plugin-firebase/quicke-build.gradle
cordova.system.library.6=com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.7=com.google.firebase:firebase-perf:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.8=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.9=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.10=com.android.support:support-annotations:27.+
cordova.system.library.11=com.android.support:support-v4:24.1.1+
cordova.system.library.12=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.13=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.14=com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0
cordova.system.library.15=com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.8.0
cordova.gradle.include.4=cordova-plugin-fcm/quicke-FCMPlugin.gradle
```

Where can I find the input string "+" and/or are there any conflicts with my plugins I installed?

**Installed plugins:**

```
cordova-plugin-advanced-http 2.0.1 "Advanced HTTP plugin"
cordova-plugin-browsertab 0.2.0 "cordova-plugin-browsertab"
cordova-plugin-buildinfo 2.0.2 "BuildInfo"
cordova-plugin-compat 1.2.0 "Compat"
cordova-plugin-customurlscheme 4.3.0 "Custom URL scheme"
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-email-composer 0.8.15 "EmailComposer"
cordova-plugin-facebook4 3.1.0 "Facebook Connect"
cordova-plugin-fcm 2.1.2 "FCMPlugin"
cordova-plugin-file 6.0.1 "File"
cordova-plugin-firebase 2.0.5 "Google Firebase Plugin"
cordova-plugin-googleplus 5.3.2 "Google SignIn"
cordova-plugin-inappbrowser 3.0.0 "InAppBrowser"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.3 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.2.0 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.1 "SocialSharing"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.2.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
cordova-universal-links-plugin 1.2.1 "Universal Links Plugin"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
```

Answer (score 0):

Issues tend to arise when multiple firebase plugins are used in the same project since each plugin will use a version of the firebase libraries. Add a variable FCM_VERSION for both the plugins in your config.xml and ensure its the same version. For example,

```
<plugin name="xxx" spec="~2.2.0">
    <variable name="FCM_VERSION" value="15.0.0" />
</plugin>
```

Comment: Okay @delwyn-pinto  I tried to add this code to my config.xml, but after I rebuilt it, same error happened.

Comment: Ok. Then its a GMS versioning issue. Uninstall the plugin, and append `--variable GMS_VERSION=11.6.2` to the cordova plugin command when you reinstall. 
In case the version number you need is different, it will show up in the console logs when you install.